# Making an immutable class

Tags: java, immutability

I'm in the process of trying to make an immutable class in which represents natural numbers. I'm using recursion in order to handle the Increment and Decrement methods. Since the fields are final, I made a private constructor to assign new values to the necessary fields when decrementing/incrementing. After testing this implementation, I can't seem to pin point the problem. If I decrement 100, it will be 10. If I increment 99, it will be 9. If I increment/decrement a number not on the bound, I will get a long string of gibberish. I guess I need a nudge in the right direction. I'm able to get it to work fine if it's mutable because i don't have to worry about the final fields.

```
public final class SlowBigNatural implements BigNatural{
final private int natural[];
final private int nSize;
final private int HIGHEST = 9;

public SlowBigNatural() {
    this.nSize = 1;
    this.natural = new int[1];
    this.natural[0] = 0;
}

public SlowBigNatural(int p) {
    this(Integer.toString(p));
}

public SlowBigNatural(String s) {
    this.nSize = s.length();
    this.natural = new int[nSize];
    for (int i = 0; i < nSize; i++) {
        this.natural[i] = Character.digit(s.charAt(i), 10);
    }
}

public SlowBigNatural(BigNatural c) {
    this(c.toString());
}

private SlowBigNatural(int[] natural, int nSize){
    this.nSize = nSize - 1;
    this.natural = new int[this.nSize];
    for (int i = 0; i < this.nSize; i++) {
        this.natural[i] = natural[i];
    } 
}

public BigNatural increment() {
    int[] nClone = new int[nSize];
    System.arraycopy(natural, 0, nClone, 0, nSize);
    if (nSize == 1 || nClone[nSize - 1] != HIGHEST) {
        nClone[nSize - 1]++;
        BigNatural nInc = new SlowBigNatural(nClone.toString());
        return nInc;
    } 

    else {
        nClone[nSize - 1] = 0;
        BigNatural temp = new SlowBigNatural(nClone, nSize);
        temp.increment();
        return temp;
    }
}

public BigNatural decrement() {
    int[] nClone = natural.clone();
    if (nClone[nSize - 1] != 0) {
        nClone[nSize - 1]--;
        BigNatural nDec = new SlowBigNatural(nClone.toString());
        return nDec;
    } 
    else {
        if (nSize != 1) {
            nClone[nSize - 1] = HIGHEST;
            BigNatural temp = new SlowBigNatural(nClone, nSize);
            temp.decrement();
            return temp;
        }
        else{
            BigNatural nDec = new SlowBigNatural(0);
            return nDec;
        }
    }
}

public String toString() {
    String nString = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < nSize; i++) {
        nString += String.valueOf(natural[i]);
    }
    return nString.replaceFirst("^0+(?!$)", "");
}
}
```

I stepped through my code, and the error seems to occur when I convert the array to a string and pass it through the constructor. It turns the array into a bunch of craziness. Continuing to investigate.

Comment: Your code doesn't make a lot of sense.  For instance, why, in this statement -- `if (nSize == 1 || nClone[nSize - 1] != HIGHEST)` -- do you test for nSize == 1??  And why, in the following else leg, do you do `temp.increment()` and then return temp, vs returning the result of `temp.increment()`, if your class is supposedly immutable??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haven't fully looked into it but if *SlowBigNatural* is really correctly immutable, then the following:

```
BigNatural temp = new SlowBigNatural(nClone, nSize);
temp.increment();
return temp;
```

is unlikely to be useful as far as I can see. The above call to *temp.increment()* creates a new object that you ignore, seen that you return *temp* itself and not the result of *temp.increment()*.

Could you try changing the above to this:

```
BigNatural temp = new SlowBigNatural(nClone, nSize);
return temp.increment();
```

And if works, do the same for *decrement()*.

Comment: I tried your suggestion, and now I'm getting random gibberish when I set a new BigNatural equal to an incremented BigNatural. I'm currently trying to step through the code, to see where exactly I'm going wrong.